# What is this macro and how has it been created?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been sent an Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet, which contains over 50 sheets. There is a contents sheet at the beginning for easier navigation around the document; there is a cell for each sheet which you can click on and be re-directed to the relevant place.

However, there are not buttons in these cells. There doesn't appear to be anything in the cell except text, where the name of the relating sheet is written. Not only will left-clicking on the cell take you to the relevant sheet, but also right-clicking and by navigating to the cell using the arrow keys on the keyboard. I've never come across anything like this before, where buttons haven't been used.

The document is protected and so I cannot delve into how the creator has managed to do this. I need to recreate this document but am completely unsure of what they have done and so cannot replicate it. I'm assuming this is some sort of macro, though there is nothing listed in the 'Macros' tool on the Developer toolbar.

The document contains sensitive information and so I cannot include a screenshot.

Comment: Sounds like just a plain old Hyperlink to me. Surely you can include a screenshot of just one cell?

Comment: Since it works with arrow keys too I'd say it works on the worksheet selection change event calling the follow hyperlink method

Comment: @jeffreyweir I can't seem to access the hyperlinks because the document is protected. Even if I could upload a screenshot, there is nothing special to show; it is literally a plain cell with some text in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find out easily if the jump table in `Sheet1` are hyperlinks (check the cursor behaviour). If not then I recon this behaviour is facilitated by a `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` trigger.

Suppose all your sheet names are listed in `Sheet1` in a range called `[JumpTable]`, then this code in `Sheet1`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("JumpTable")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
            Sheets(Target.Value).Activate
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

will get you to the sheet whose name you click on `Sheet1`.

The rest is up to your imagination!

Comment: Definitely aren't hyperlinks and that code works a treat!